# How to fix position 'Matrix.translationValues' in Transform animation Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have created custom floating action bar including animation sub menu using Matrix4.translationValues.

You can check my [gists here](https://gist.github.com/kazhuyo/f61e4cc6fd6efd385f2d49579c9952e5)

Here's my code for sub menu animation position after Floating Action Button pressed :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 1.8,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: add(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            _translateButton.value * 0.8,
            _translateButton.value * 1.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: image(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 1.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: inbox(),
        ),
        toggle(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here's screenshoot the output above the code :
[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98LfB.jpg)

My question is how to set the last sub menu item into right position, not at the center position ?

Comment: what's the code you are using when call AnimatedFab ?

Comment: @diegoveloper Just using  floatingActionButton: AnimatedFab(),

Comment: it's working fine for me, the button is placed at the bottom - right

Comment: @diegoveloper I want inbox widget at the right side, not in the center. and have you tried with floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move your INBOX button to the right , you have to use negative value for the X axis, like this:

```
 Transform(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
        _translateButton.value * -0.8,
        _translateButton.value * 1.0,
        0.0,
      ),
      child: inbox(),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I wanted.